# mat-chip angular-material-design not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

If I enter some string it did not show in proper design within his side textbox value set.

HTML

```
      <mat-form-field class="favorite-fruits">
        <mat-label>Favorite Fruits</mat-label>
        <mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Fruit selection">
          <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" (removed)="remove(fruit)">
            {{fruit.name}}
            <button matChipRemove>
              <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
            </button>
          </mat-chip>
          <input placeholder="New fruit..."
                 [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
                 (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
        </mat-chip-list>
      </mat-form-field>
```

ts

```
import { COMMA, ENTER } from '@angular/cdk/keycodes';
import { MatChipInputEvent } from '@angular/material/chips';

export interface Fruit {
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-story',
  templateUrl: './my-story.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-story.component.scss']
})
export class MyStoryComponent implements OnInit {
      fruits: Fruit[] = [];
    
      add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
        const value = (event.value || '').trim();
    
        // Add our fruit
        if (value) {
          this.fruits.push({name: value});
        }
      }
    
      remove(fruit: Fruit): void {
        const index = this.fruits.indexOf(fruit);
    
        if (index >= 0) {
          this.fruits.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
}
```

css

```
.favorite-fruits {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

This is the link I used for it:-
https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using Angular below v12 and checked the docs for v12+.

Angular v12 and lower:

```
<mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
```

Angular v12+:

```
<button matChipRemove>
    <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
</button>
```